# map quest traffic flow api

Tags: javascript, dictionary, traffic, mapquest

Is there a way to add the map quest traffic flow api to a control with an existing map from map box?

If been trying to add the map quest layer to my control and it is not working at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get MapQuest traffic is to use the [MapQuest traffic plugin for Leaflet](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/traffic/).